# If vector space has finite dimension, then algebra is finitely generated

Tags: reference-request, vector-spaces, solution-verification, finitely-generated

Suppose we have a $\mathbb{K}$-vector-space $V$ which has finite dimension, so in particular $V=\langle v_1,\dots,v_n \rangle_{\mathbb{K}}$ ($V$ is generated as a vector space by $v_1,\dots,v_n$). Suppose $V \subseteq A$ where $A$ is a $\mathbb{K}$-algebra (commutative with $1$ and the scalar multiplication of $V$ is just the scalar multiplication of $A$). Then I claim that
$$ \langle V \rangle_A=\langle v_1, \dots, v_n \rangle_A $$
where we write $\langle B \rangle_A$ for the $\mathbb{K}$-algebra (commutative with $1$) generated by a set $B \subseteq A$. In particular, a finite dimensional vector space generates a finitely generated algebra.

Proof idea: Elements in $\langle V \rangle_A $ are of the form $\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i \cdot x_1 \cdots x_{m_i} + \sum_{k=1}^{l} \beta_k \cdot 1$ for $\alpha_i, \beta_k \in \mathbb{K},x_j \in V$ (where $1$ is the identity in $A$). All elements $x_j$ can be written as $x_j = \sum_{i=1}^n \gamma_{j,i} \, v_i$ for $\gamma_{j,i} \in \mathbb{K}$. Hence, all elements in $\langle V \rangle_A$ can be written as polynomials in $v_1,\dots,v_n$ over $\mathbb{K}$.

Is the statement above true? If so, do you know of any references for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is true and the proof you gave works just fine. Here's another idea that requires writing fewer sums. $\langle B \rangle_A$ is the smallest $\mathbb K$ subalgebra of $A$ that contains $B$. So certainly $\langle v_1, \dots v_n \rangle_A \subseteq \langle V\rangle_A$. On the other hand, let $v\in V$. Then $v=\sum a_i v_i$ so $v \in \langle v_1,\dots,v_n\rangle_A$. Hence, $V\subseteq \langle v_1,\dots,v_n\rangle_A$ and we have $\langle V\rangle_A \subseteq \langle v_1,\dots,v_n\rangle_A \subseteq \langle V\rangle_A$. This is the desired equality.

Comment: Thank you! Your direct argument makes the statement even simpler! I will still hold on before accepting the answer in case someone knows of a reference where this has been discussed.